# How can I issue mstsc in batch mode, no console session?

Tags: powershell, mstsc

I need to issue mstsc and get a status back that this command works for a series of IPs. No RDP console.

I cannot use WMI ports, just RDP 3389 to the device. Would love to use PowerShell remote commands but I read they use WMIObjects which implies using WMI ports.

I used psexec and it uses WMI ports. This worked in my lab but when I hit the real firewalls, blocked.

I've tried several methods, each hits the WMI ports or causes the RDP console to pop on the from server. I also need the event to report back connected or not found into a file for further decision making.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to test to see if TCP 3389 is open?

Answer (score 0):

Terminal Services were made for interactive use, not batch mode. If you want to check if a port is accessible in PowerShell you can try to establish a TCP connection to it:

```
$servers = ...

foreach ($server in $servers) {
  $clnt = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
  try {
    $clnt.Connect($server, 3389)
    "$server:`tOK"
  } catch {
    "$server:`tnot available"
  } finally {
    $clnt.Dispose()
  }
}
```

On more recent Windows versions there's also [`Test-NetConnection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn372891.aspx):

```
$servers = ...

foreach ($server in $servers) {
  Test-NetConnection -Computer $server -Port 3389
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I should have mentioned we did this solution and it seemed to work. My issue is they have a IP forwarding server in the middle so Socket stops at that server.  The RDP port seemed to be open but it was not. This answer is correct and works well in normal architectures. You did address my overall concern, RDP is a terminal services function so I'm trying to make something do what it can't. Thanks for your info. and I will try Test-NetConnection as well. That one I didn't do.

Comment: Hmm... for a scenario like that you may want to take a look at [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/rdp-enum-encryption.html).

Comment: Ansgar, you read my mind. Another team is using NMAP and I wanted to stay away from using it. I'm a NMAP novice but will soon not be. Folks on the security team hate seeing NMAP in my world, but it is what it is. I'm marching toward NMAP.

Comment: Now, what do I do go get NMAP running off MS OS?

Comment: For the Windows port of `nmap` see [here](https://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html), but this isn't really programming-related, so further questions should go to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).