# Powershell script to establish connectivity to remote server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have a requirement wherein I have to test the connectivity to the destination server (which sometimes goes down due to network issues).

So basically, I need to check that if it goes down due to any reason, the PowerShell script should be able to bring it back up.

I am able to write a script which will test the connectivity to the destination server which has been listed below. But do not know how to re-establish the connectivity when the network goes down.

Can anyone help me add the "Establish connectivity" part of it.

```
$servers = "server name"

Clear-Content c:\myprocesses.txt

foreach ($s in $servers) {
  if (!(Test-Connection -Cn $s -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -EA 0 -Quiet)) {
    "Problem connecting to $s"
    "Flushing DNS"
    ipconfig /flushdns | Out-Null

    "Registering DNS"
    ipconfig /registerdns | Out-Null

    "doing a NSLookup for $s"
    nslookup $s >> C:\myprocesses.txt
    "Re-pinging $s"

    if (!(Test-Connection -Cn $s -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)) {
      "Problem still exists in connecting to $s"
    } else {
      "Resolved problem connecting to $s"
    } # end if

    tracert $s >> c:\myprocesses.txt
  } else {
    Enable-PSRemoting -Force
    Restart-Service WinRM

    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $s -Quiet) {
      New-PSSession $s
    }

    "No Problem connecting to $s"
    "Writing the Traceroute to the destination server $s"
    tracert $s >> c:\myprocesses.txt

    "c:\myprocesses.txt ready" 
  } # end if
} # end foreach`
```

Comment: What are you talking about? If the network goes down there is no re-establishing connectivity until the network becomes operational again. There's nothing you can do on any particular server to fix that. Or do you mean network configuration/interface problems on a server? The answer to that would depend on what causes the problem. Also, are you talking about the machine where this script is running, or the remote servers?

Comment: Yes, I have deployed the script to one of the source servers. There are connectivity issues between the CRM services running in server 1 and server 2.  We would like to  force a reconnection between servers in an all functioning network.

Comment: Restart the relevant client and/or server applications once the other side responds to ping (or a [TCP connect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35140754/1630171)) again.